# Why does DATEDIFF return -1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm trying to understand how the DATEDIFF function works in SQL Server. The following T-SQL returns -1:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2015-10-25, 2015-12-27)
```

However, ending_date is after start_date so I would expect a positive number, not a negative number.  Further, I would expect that the difference between Oct 25 and Dec 27 to be 2 months.  Instead, SQL Server is returning -1 month.  Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Hint:  those aren't dates.

Comment: You need to enclose those in quotes. What you have there for the first value is `2015 MINUS 10 MINUS 25` and the second value is `2015 MINUS 12 MINUS 27`

Comment: Are you sure the values get cast to dates properly? Looks like integer subtraction to me

Comment: This is a beautiful confluence of T-SQL's lack of a dedicated syntax for date/time literals plus the implicit conversion from `INT` to `DATETIME`. A gotcha for the books. Even better, since `DATETIME` uses the integer portion of its value for whole days, we have `DATEDIFF(DAY, 2015-10-01, 2015-10-05) = -DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-05')`. Woe betide the poor developer who "fixes" it by inverting the sign...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing apostrophes:

```
SELECT  2015-10-25 AS First, 
        2015-12-27 AS Second,
        CAST(2015-10-25 As DateTime) AS [First as datetime],
        CAST(2015-12-27 As DateTime) AS [Second as datetime],
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2015-10-25, 2015-12-27) AS WrongResult,
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-10-25', '2015-12-27') AS CorrectResult
```

Results:

```
First   Second  First as datetime       Second as datetime      WrongResult CorrectResult
1980    1976    04.06.1905 00:00:00     31.05.1905 00:00:00     -1          2
```

SQL Server looks at `2015-10-25` as an int - the result of the mathematical expression (1980).
The usage of `int` in `datetime` functions cause SQL Server to implicitly convert the `int` value to a `DateTime` value.
The `int` value represents the number of days since `'1900-01-01'` - and since the second argument results in a smaller int value, you get a negative number.

As Jeroen Mostert wrote in his comment - A gotcha for the books.

Answer (score 5):

You are not quoting your dates, this means your expression evaluates to:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, 1980, 1976)
```

Which after implicit conversion to datetime evaluates to:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1905-06-04 00:00:00.000', '1905-05-31 00:00:00.000')
```

So now the startdate is after the enddate.

Comment: To be clear.  1980 as a datetime is 1905-06-04   ....   select convert(Datetime,2015-10-25)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using numbers (integers specifically), not strings. `2015-10-25 = 1980`  which, when you convert to a date is  `'1905-06-04'`. On the other hand `2015-12-27 = 1976`, which as a date is `'1905-05-31'`. As `'1905-05-31'` is one month before `'1905-06-04'` you get the result -1.

Use literal strings, and `yyyyMMdd` dates:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20151025', '20151227');
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the date values within single quotes.

**Query**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-10-25', '2015-12-27');
```

This query returns `2` as the output.